# Why I receive invalid context 0x0 error in document-based applications?

Tags: objective-c, cgcontext, cgcontextref

I use this code to draw some rects in a view.
 This is the code:

```
CGContextRef myContext =  [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 1, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 200, 100 ));
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0, 0, 1, .5);
CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 100, 200));
```

When I use the code in a simple `AppDelegate`, everything is okay. But, when I use it in any Document-based application (in `Document.m`), I receive this error:

```
<Error>: CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I think I was an idiot !. the current context is always set to main window. I could mange it by subclassing a view and using this code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```